# Cant create GitHub repository using bash

Tags: bash, github, github-api

When we run the following bash script:
This script is supposed to be called to create a github repository. When we hardcode the data it works fine but this would not be practical if we wanted to use this in a bigger script. We also plan to change out the reads for arguments in the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Username and password variables to access the github account
USERNAME="USERNAME"

#Github repository name and project description is neccesary to make the remote repository
echo What would you like your github repository to be called?
read githubrepo
echo Write out your project description
read projdes

#Remote github repository is created 
#curl -u $USERNAME  https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$githubrepo","description":"$projdes"}'

NEWVAR="{\"name\":\"$githubrepo\", \"description\":\"$projdes\"}"
echo $NEWVAR
curl -u $USERNAME https://api.github.com/users/repos -d $NEWVAR
#curl -u $USERNAME "https://api.github.com/users/repos" -d "{\"name\":\"$githubrepo\", \"description\": \"$projdes\"}"
```

We get:

```
{"name":"lkj", "description":"lj"} E
Enter host password for user 'USERNAME':
 {   "message": "Not Found",   "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest" }
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 19
```

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

How can we fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly add the right quotes (according to the Github documentation) and there are multiple ways, using both double `"` and single `'` quotes.

I think your `NEWVAR` should be assigned like this:

```
NEWVAR="'{\"name\":\"$githubrepo\",\"description\":\"$projdes\"}'"
```

which will produce the following output:

```
'{"name":"qwe","description":"123"}'
```

Comment: I end up with this:
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 20:
"description":"bar"}'

Comment: The space after the comma seemed to be the problem. It worked for me with the new version. :)

Comment: I tried deleting it but it still just says problems parsing JSON.

Comment: Did you try with my version?

Comment: You only need the single quotes at the start and end of `NEWVAR` because you are not quoting it when it is used.  If you do `"$NEWVAR"` where you want to use it you can drop the start/end single quotes inside of the variable.

Comment: That is how I have it. If you have the working code, could we use it? edit: My friend found figured it out. Thank you.